# Overhead light fixture won’t unscrew

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I managed to pull out the pull string on an overhead light fixture. I went to go unscrew the fixture and it only unscrews a little bit before hard stopping. It looks to me like there’s a wire surrounding the screw, and I’m wondering if this is some sort of screw lock? And if I will need to pull it off with pliers.

Pic attached[image: Picture of offending overhead light fixture screw and wire]

Answer (score 1):

That is a wire that someone wrapped around the decorative nut for reasons unknown.

Remove the wire and it should unscrew easily.  Or use pliers to grip the nut and unscrew it.

Comment: I took it out, looks like it was just a spacer. Now the light fixture won't unscrew but that's another issue.